# How to remove Unicode characters in Snowflake?

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to clean data in snowflake table and I see a lot of unicode characters like `\U0028`.
I wrote the following, but not sure how to remove the Unicode.

```
Select
REGEXP_REPLACE(
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
               REGEXP_REPLACE(lower('MON \U0028 POP STORE'),
                              '[/-_.,&#\'"?~;/+|:|/|]'),
               '( co|inc|pllc|llc|ltd|plc|corp|pc|corporation|incorporated)$'),
           '\\s+',
           ' ') ;
```

Is the regex possible or I need to use `REPLACE(`data`, '\\u0028', '\\u0306')`. Any help would be appreciated.

My data looks like:

```
VITAMIN \U0026 SUPPLEMENTS STORE
```

Comment: `\U0026` is all ascii characters. If it were an escape sequence interpolated in a string, the capital `U` requires 8 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions depending on what those entities are in real life.

If these are char hex entities and `\u0026` is in fact a `&` char that is shown as `\u0026` in the console, you probably do not need to take any action since it is OK as is.

If these are *literal* substrings you want to remove from the text you may use

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( input, '\\s*\\\\U\\d{4}', '' )
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lfq5JG/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cs*%5C%5CU%5Cd%7B4%7D):

[image]

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\\` - a backslash
- `U` - a `U` char
- `\d{4}` - four digits.

Note that inside the string literal each backslash must be escaped twice as `\` is used in strings to form string escape sequences like `\n` (newline), `\t` (tab), etc. See [**Escape Characters and Caveats**](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html#escape-characters-and-caveats).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that here we might only want to find our unicodes using a simple expression, maybe such as:

```
\\U.+?(\s)
```

and replace it with an empty string.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0nU9Ds/1/)